# How to hand over many commands into expect command?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have to connect with `ssh` to server and run a lot of commands.
Solution as I know is script like this

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho ssh '"admin"@"server"' "sudo bash -c \"command1\"";
      expect "*assword:*"; send "'${user_password}'\r";
      expect eof'
```

repeated several times. But I don't want to connect every time.

Maybe you know how to run command1 command2 ... in one connection?

Thank you

Comment: why dont you create a script on your server and execute that script instead?

Comment: I can't, because it are several servers, and I should connect anyway

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. Connect and run script from file on server. I can't because it is server setting operation, I should configure something, so server should be clear

Comment: Use public-key authorization and configure `sudo` properly, and you won't need `expect` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man ssh, you can do

```
ssh [user@]hostname [command]
```

you can also pipe commands and use multiple commands like this:

```
ssh user@hostname "command1; command2; command3"
```

@SMA is also correct, you can create a script on your server and use:

```
ssh user@hostname 'bash myscript.sh'
```

Comment: Thank you, I just rewrite my expect command as you reminded me correct syntax of ssh

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @LittlePanic404's answer:

```sh
ssh user@hostname "command1; command2; command3"
```

can also be written with newlines, which is quite readable. Also, use the shell's quoted heredocs, and use the environment to pass shell variables into expect:

```sh
export user host password

expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    spawn -noecho ssh $env(user)@$env(host) {
        command1
        command2
        command3
    }
    expect "*assword:*" {send "$env(password)\r"}
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

Note that expect is an Tcl extension, and Tcl uses `{braces}` the same way the shell uses `'single quotes'`